# How can I upload files to google cloud storage without token in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, token

I want to upload images to my bucket in google cloud storage.

I tried to make a post like that :

```
let response = await fetch(
          `https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=test.png`,

          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: file,
          }
        );
```

I get The token from [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).
And everything was good, But The token expired in one hour.

How can I allow to upload files from anywhere without a token or if I can get a token with a long expiration time?

Comment: Imagine allowing anyone to upload stuff to your storage bucket. Without a token or signed URL, that is what would happen.

Comment: I mean anywhere not anyone because you will guess my bucket name, However, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

No token means no authorization. So, yes you can, you can allow anyone on the internet to load file in your bucket without authorization check! But, it's obviously not a good idea.

The other solution is to generate a [signedURL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to allow the customer to upload the file.

---

**EDIT 1**

To generate an upload signed URL use the PUT HTTP verb. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4) it is documented

Comment: Yes, I know that, but this operation is complicated and deprecated in javascript.
Than you guillaume blaquiere

Comment: Excuse me, @guillaume blaquiere The signedURL just helped me to get the special file, But I want to upload this file to google cloud not download it.

Comment: Here it is: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4

Comment: Thanks, @guillaume blaquiere , but my code is only javascript.